# Sprint MVC App using Thymeleaf Unable to find CSS with standard href?

Tags: java, html, css, spring, thymeleaf

I'm having some problems trying with path structure in a MVC app. There were some similar older questions on this site, but none that resolved or explained my question.

This is the href I am using when I am testing my html. It works fine, and the css is resolved properly.

```
href="../static/css/main.css"
```

But when I start up the server, and thymeleaf and spring return the view - I get pure html and none of my css files were resolved. None of the static content is resolved. They all are coming back with 404s.

I can get them to resolve properly if I add the thymeleaf href tag using a different relative path root:

```
th:href="@{/css/main.css}"
```

But shouldn't these be the same? Clearly the application is resolving the path differently than I am seeing when just working with the html. But I am unsure why, and how to get the application to find the right path. I don't really want to have to include a unique href AND th:href into the html if I can avoid it.

My folder structure is what I thought the standard was:

```
/resources/templates/home.html
/resources/static/css/main.css
/resources/static/images/pic.jpg
/resources/static/js/action.js
```

I do not have `@EnableWebMVC` in use, and have no `web.xml`. The controller for this is barebones.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
```

Using:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '2.0.0.M7'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools', version: '2.0.0.M7'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.0.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.0.0.M7'
```

Looking through the Thymeleaf docs, I do see an example of exactly what I am describing. So maybe it is expected? I would love to understand better why though.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" 
      href="../../css/gtvg.css" th:href="@{/css/gtvg.css}" />
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.  Your controller code looks fine.

Your first path, `href="../static/css/main.css"`, allows the CSS to be displayed when the page is not run through any container or without any processing by Thymeleaf.  Having this ability allows you give the HTML directly to a UI designer without the designer having to know anything about Java functionality or needing to load Tomcat/Spring to view the page.  This is a huge benefit over other choices (namely, JSP) to render your view.  This is a *relative* path from the HTML file.

The second path of `th:href="@{/css/main.css}"` tells Thymeleaf where to find the file in the context of a running container, using a path relative to the *server* (container).  Think of it like a document root.

Each serves a different purpose and while you can omit the first path entirely from your running application, your CSS will not display when you open the page directly with a browser without a running container.  You will need the second at a minimum on your live site.

Therefore, a complete example would typically contain both paths.